# Please explain this circuit (CNY70, Zener diode)

Tags: zener, photodiode

I am trying to build a new (Arduino based) controller for a machine that contains a circuit that uses a CNY70 to detect RPMs in a motor.  The circuit takes a 5V input and I accidentally gave it 24 volts and likely blew something out.  My controller is not just for this machine, I will be making them for others as well (this is not a "how do I repair" question). And to get the controller working, I need to understand this circuit.

Here is the circuit diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJXIfY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Again - I didn't create this circuit, just trying to understand it.

The correct behavior is that it will output 5v normally, and will output 0v when a reflector on the wheel that the motor turns passes over the CNY70.

I am an electronics newbie, and can't make sense of how this works.  If I measure VCC vs GND on my voltmeter, I read 1.6 volts when the voltage is connected to this circuit, and 5 volts when not.  So it's being fed 5V in VCC, but the circuit drops it to 1.6V.

I have actually wired up a different CNY70 circuit myself, but didn't have the Zener diode in there.  That's the part that I'm struggling with the most.  The writing on the diode says "3V9" and "BZX".

Here is a section of the logic PCB this connects to.  On this, pin 24 on the DB25 connector is VCC (yellow wire), 25 is signal (green), and 10 and 11 are GND.

[image: Top]
[image: Bottom]
[image: CNY70 PCB]

Update: to answer the question 3 below:
When I measure the current between yellow and white (vcc and gnd), with this circuit disconnected, going through a 60 ohm resister as requested - I get 1 milliamp of current.  When I connect the resistor directly between VCC and GND, and measure the voltage, I get 1.379V.

Update - regarding R2.  When I created this schematic, I was going by the readings I got when examining the components on the blown circuit, which I did a couple of weeks ago.  If you look at the picture, I know the "blue thing" (R2) looks like a cap, but I had convinced myself it was a resistor that just looked like a cap based on reading resistance off of it (100k ohms).  Now after examining that component on the working machine, I'm not so sure.  What it says on it is: "XK 104".  So that would indicate it's a 100nF cap?  If I read the capacitance on it, I get 171nF.  For grins, I measured the resistance, and that's 13 mOhms.  So - sorry!!!!  It is a cap, isn't it.  I am so sorry for adding to the confusion here.  Please confirm my mistake, and does that clear things up?  Certainly not for me, I don't know what a cap would be doing in this circuit.

Update: Regarding the zener diode.  If I diode test the one in the working machine, I get .7 volts, and 1.056V Zener voltage (putting the positive lead of my voltmeter on the cathode side).  Shouldn't it be 3.9v?

- Dave

Comment: It is a cap and not overly significant, even as a 100k resistor. The cap is there to reduce the noise on Vin, presumably from the motor(s). 0.1uF is a "magic number" for low-voltage electronics; as a general rule of thumb, one should be added across the power supply pins of every IC.

Comment: Awesome. My controller will be feeding this circuit 5v, not 6. Can you tell me what I should use for rpullup and ryellow given that?

Comment: Added calcs for R's to my answer. It will just take a sec ;)

Comment: Ok, I get that if I still use a 220 ohm resistor for ryellow "X" will be 15.5ma. So 220 still works with a vcc of 5V. So now I know how to repair the circuit, and how to connect to it from my comtroller. Thanks!  But I still don't understand how it works. Would you mind walking me through that? How is it that I read 1.6v between vcc and gnd when the circuit is connected. And why does it output 5V when the CNY70 is seeing a dark color (outputting near 0v), and 0v when it's seeing a light color (outputting near 5v).

Comment: Added additional info to answer. The LED is always on while the sensor is connected so there is a constant voltage drop across the LED, R1, and Ryellow. Ryellow was given the highest resistance so that the majority of the voltage would drop across it, instead of the LED (and Zener), before it even gets to the sensor.

Comment: Wow!!  John - this is truly amazing.  Thank you for all your help and all the time you put into this!  I wish there was some way I could repay you.  I think I've got it now.  A couple of points below.

Comment: Technically the sensor in the CNY70 is a phototransistor, not a photodiode.  Not sure if it matters in terms of your explanation.  I didn't know you could force current against the emitter in the CNY70.  I actually built a different circuit using a CNY70 to detect RPMs, and used a Schmidt trigger to detect the on/off cycles.  That seems the more traditional way to use the device.  Any idea why they did it this way?  Maybe to avoid issues with the long run between the controller and the machine?

Comment: Also, since I measure 10k ohms between green and white, should I add a 10k pull down resistor between green and gnd in my controller (and in the circuit above)?

Comment: Good catch; got that fixed. Re: "force current against.." - Rather than conceptualizing current being **forced** against it, imagine that **everyone** gets on the same 100-lane highway to go home. Let's say everyone is 10k people and that a 100-lane highway could carry 20k people home quickly (minimal-traffic). Now, imagine that 99 of those 100 lanes are closed today. Everyone will still try to use the highway, because it's **A** way home but traffic piles up and people look for alternate routes. The lucky few that got to the lane-closures first, got home on time; everyone else was late.

Comment: Re: "Any idea why they did it this way?" IMO, because people like you and I haven't given them a run for their money yet. That logic board is proprietary, large, expensive, etc. If it costs you $50.0 to buy a replacement from them, I'd guess it would cost them about **$5.00 each** (when ordering >1,000). By making this proprietary, they are making a fortune! **You** could probably replicate the entire logic board with an ATTiny85 for about $10 (for one, soldered by hand) :D

Comment: As long as the pull-up is weak, and very close to the logic, you are pretty much guaranteed a near-vertical slew-rate. For an ATTiny running at 5V, voltages >= 3V are considered "ON", while voltages <= 1.5V are considered "OFF". There is a noticeable gap in-between the two and if your input voltages fall within that gap, you will need some type of input buffer like your trigger. As long as the cable is not **ridiculously** long, your logic should get a very strong 5V/<1.5V signal on GREEN without special hardware.

Comment: Consider adding current and voltage protection to GREEN, close to the logic. You know, in case someone hooks it up backward or gives it 24V.. :D (You have to **design** which part explodes when things go wrong)

Comment: The cable is about 8 feet long.  Pretty standard DB25 cable.  So did you add the pulldown resistor to the circuit diagram?  I still don't see it.  And if it is in there, shouldn't I see 20k ohms between VCC and gnd?  I don't - I see 1.8K ohms.

Comment: Adding a pull-down of the same value would cut GREEN HIGH in half and you don't want that. There is probably another resistor in series with GREEN between the schematic and the actual logic IC; I alluded to it in my most recent comment regarding protection for GREEN. The second image you posted is blurry and I can't read the values; I was only able to see how the DB25 pin connected to the resistors on the front side. If you understand the relation between the photo in my answer and the physical PCB, you can explore with your multimeter and track it down.

Comment: Rotating back-side photos by 180 and flipping them horizontally will correlate photos of the two sides.

Comment: Added final photo to my answer for a possible clue to finding that mystery resistance. Please accept my answer, if you are happy with it.

Comment: No, that trace you highlighted isn't GREEN.  You were right the first time - it goes into that 10k resistor.  From there, it goes straight to a pin in a shift register.  Thanks again, Jon!

Comment: This is exactly why we discourage broad, open-ended questions relating to the reverse engineering and/or repair of devices here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow certain questions about reverse engineering in which you explain in detail what you know about the circuit and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts.

Comment: Dave Tweed - thst seems to me exactly what happened here. I'm not sure how what we discussed violated the rules of the site, and I guess I don't care. But it was very helpful to me. Maybe this thread should be moved to another group?  It does seem like this is an interesting circuit for others to look at. But now that my question has been answered, I guess I don't care about what happens to this, other than that Jon should get "credit" for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am an electronics newbie, and can't make sense of how this works. If
>   I measure VCC vs GND on my voltmeter, I read 1.6 volts when the
>   voltage is connected to this circuit, and 5 volts when not. So it's
>   being fed 5V in VCC, but the circuit drops it to 1.6V.

With the sensor disconnected, there is no load after R1, so Vout=Vin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkg8Ac.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the sensor connected, **The math:** below happens. The photo-transistor does not conduct when it doesn't see light, so GREEN is floating (disconnected/Hi-Z) on the sensor end, and pulled-up to 5V on the logic end; with no load, GREEN stays at 5V. When light hits the photo-transistor, it connects GREEN to WHITE, easily overriding the few-milliamps supplied by the pull-up; GREEN goes to 0V. The reflector passes, the photo-transistor stops conducting, Rpullup pulls GREEN back up to 5V. Repeat, repeat, repeat... This all produces a square wave on GREEN; the frequency of the wave is directly related to the RPM of the reflector. 
Assuming the reflective and non-reflective surfaces are in equal proportion, the duty-cycle of the square wave is a (fixed) 50%. The logic measures the time between one ON and the next to determine the RPMs.

Here is an animated explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_LqDp7LErM

---

Ok!
Today, we confirmed:
-The Zener is only for over-voltage protection for LED
-The capacitor is a capacitor and will keep the LED from flickering
-Rpullup = 10kohm pull-up in remote logic
-Ryellow = 220ohm resistor in series with YELLOW

The schematic now explains the 1.6V measurement while connected.

**The math:**

```
Vdrop(LED + R1 + Ryellow) = Vin = 6V
Vdrop(LED) ~ 1.25V (datasheet)
Vdrop(R1 + Ryellow) = 6V - 1.25V = 4.75V
Vdrop(R1) = 4.75V * (R1 / (R1 + Ryellow)) = 0.43V
Vdrop(Ryellow) = 4.75V * (Ryellow / (R1 + Ryellow)) = 4.32V
```

See it?
[image]

[image]

> Awesome. My controller will be feeding this circuit 5v, not 6. Can you tell me what I should use for rpullup and ryellow given that?

Please check for yourself by re-calculating **The math:**, from above, using 5V for Vin; you need the new value of Vdrop(R1) below:

```
-The current through R1 and LED are equal  
-Typical LED current is 10-20mA; max for this one is 50mA  
E = I * R  
I = E / R  
(Iled = Ir1) = (Vdrop(R1) / R1) = X

If 10mA < X < 50mA, you are good to go!
```

Comment: My version of the schematic shows R2 as 22 ohms, not 220.

Comment: I don't know how to make it clearer. My screen shows R2 as having a value of 22. Are you saying it ought to be 220?

Comment: R2 is 22 ohms.  It's red, red, black, gold. And it does measure 22 ohms on my multimeter. So where does that leave us?  Could one of you please summarize your suggestions as to what I should do?  Have a pull-up resistor of how much?  Anything else I should test?  Like the Zener?  How would I test it to see if it's blown?  And can you explain what I said in the original post: ". If I measure VCC vs GND on my voltmeter, I read 1.6 volts when the voltage is connected to this circuit, and 5 volts when not. So it's being fed 5V in VCC, but the circuit drops it to 1.6V."  Thanks!

Comment: This is what I was talking about when I said "I am an electronics newbie, and can't make sense of how this works. If I measure VCC vs GND on my voltmeter, I read 1.6 volts when the voltage is connected to this circuit, and 5 volts when not. So it's being fed 5V in VCC, but the circuit drops it to 1.6V."

Comment: It's 5v when I read the voltage output to the yellow wire when not connected to the circuit in my diagram. I see now that you modified the diagram in my original post. Thanks!  I think. How did you even do that?  Can you modify it to have the yellow and white wires labelled, that we have been referring to?  And are you sure about that pull-up resistor?  It's not on the PCB that has the circuit I diagrammed, but like you said - it could be in the original controller.

Comment: (continued...) How can I verify that?  I can open up the original controller, but its full of SMD components and a bit difficult for me to decipher.

Comment: Yes, I do - whether or not the CNY circuit is connected to the logic side, I measure 5V on GREENWIRE.

Comment: And - I don't think I said, but I also have a brand new version of this machine for comparison, that I did not fry whatever I fried on the circuit above.  I did find a difference between that one and this - probably a clue.  On the fried machine, I measure 6.1V on the yellow wire (VCC) (logic side) when the circuit above is connected, and 4.1V when not connected.  On the new machine, I measure 1.6V when connected, and 6V when not connected (!).  Can you make sense of that?

Comment: Also, I did some resistance measurements and don't know if they show anything.  On both machines I measure 10K ohms between GREENWIRE and VCC (yellow wire) and also 10K between GREENWIRE and ground.

Comment: Yes, confirmed.

Comment: I added some images to the original post.

Comment: ... and answered your question 3 above (answered in the original post).

Comment: And added an update on R2.  Is it a cap?

Comment: Added some measurements to the Zener.  Can you let me know what kind of Zener I need to get?  I ordered some 3.9v zeners, but after measuring, I'm wondering do I need a 1v zener?  I will replace the 100k resistor in my repaired circuit with a cap, and add a 5k pullup resistor in my controller.  Anything else to complete the repair?  Thanks again, Jon - you are a lifesaver!

Comment: And can you explain why I'm reading 171nf on the cap when the marking indicate it should be 100nf?

Comment: All components have a tolerance; the cheapest caps are +-20%. If that one is the one that got the 24V, it may have been partially-destroyed as well. Also, if you didn't remove it from the circuit, you are measuring the capacitance of the circuit, not the capacitor. Same goes for the Zener, since it's Zener voltage is the LED's forward voltage too.

Comment: Don't add anything to the controller! We know how it's really supposed to work now, so you should be able to determine exactly how the possibly-fried machine differs.

Comment: The one I measured was on the new machine, not the fried one.  Being 70% higher than 100nf seems way outside the tolerance, isn't it?  So I guess it's the capacitance of the circuit, although I was measuring between the solder junctions of the cap on the pcb.  Same with the Zener.  I do have a couple 100nf caps, so ok to use one of those?  Not sure if I need to worry about anything other than the capacitance at this voltage...  And regarding modifying the controller - I was talking about adding the pullup to the new controller I'm building to control this machine, not the existing controller.

Comment: Understood about pullup, but wait for the schematic edit to come through; Rpullup is actually 10k. Capacitor is ceramic and needs to be rated for >=10V. Always round up and double-(3.9V + 1V) * 2 = 9.8V. Do you intend to control this with 5V logic (Arduino)?

Comment: BTW, without Ryellow, just 6V would destroy the entire board since the Zener would melt from trying to bring an unlimited amount of 6V down to 3.9V (possibly taking the remote logic with it). Before it melted, the LED and R1 would have to drop 3.9V, destroying the LED. Assuming the Zener gave out first, the LED and R1 would then have to drop 6V, super-destroying the LED. This is at just 6V, so you can probably imagine how fast everything got toasted at 24V. I could have saved us a couple of days if I'd asked for photos first; sorry. :D

Answer (score 3):

There's a very good reason you can't figure out how the circuit works: you're not showing the entire circuit. Please edit your post to provide either a link to the circuit, or an explanation of how it was produced.

To begin with, with 5 volts in and a 22 ohm resistor, the current through the LED will be in the neighborhood of 150 mA, and it's only rated for 50 continuous. This suggests that the input voltage should be less than 5 volts.  Voltage across the resistor is Vin - 1.6 (the forward voltage), so you can figure the current through the resistor by Ohm's Law. For a current limit of 50 mA, this means the input voltage should be roughly 2.5 volts.

Secondly, the circuit ground is probably connected to C rather than E, with the output connected to E rather than C.

Finally, there will be somewhere (maybe back at the unit the 3 wires attach to), a resistor from the output (E) to +5, with a value of about 5k or more.

When you connected 24 volts to the input, if the zener did not die it protected the the LED by limiting the voltage to ~4 volts. This is still too high, but it's clearly intended for short-duration overvoltages.

Comment: I produced the circuit in the picture, by examining the PCB, testing connections with a continuity tester, etc.  The ground is connected to C, that's what I'm showing, and output is connected to E...  I'm not sure what other info I can give you, but let me know if you have any other questions.  And if you could enlighten me as to how this circuit functions, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I suspect that you've misread the data sheet. If you look closely at the drawings, I strongly suspect you've switched the emitter and collector of the ouput phototransistor. Certainly what you have drawn does not match what's on the data sheet, either in terms of symbol or of physical package.

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot about the zener. LED Vf is typically 1.25 volts, and maximum zener voltage is 4.1, so max current is roughly (4.1 - 1.25) / 22, or 130 mA. Still way over max for the LED.

Comment: Here's a data sheet for the zener http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/344206/DIOTECH/BZX3V9/592/2/BZX3V9.html note (p.2) that the zener voltage can be as high as 4.1

Comment: Actually, it equals .1294545454....  Please adjust your calculator to show more than three significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opto-isolated feedback circuit for some sort of controlling circuitry.

The yellow is the non-isolated feedback from some remote logic. This is clamped by the zener such that it does not exceed the zener voltage. That then forward biases the LED in the opto-isoator. The photodiode in the opto conducts proportionately to the forward current of the LED in the opto. This provides an electrically isolated feedback signal to the green lead.

You'll see this sometimes in AC/DC converters where the yellow signal needs to be galvanically isolated from the green for safety reasons.

Comment: No new information here.. Did you reply to the title without reading the [extensive] dialog? Also, because of the pull-up (currently "somewhere"), it's not even really isolated from... itself? I'm waiting to hear back with a 100%-certain comparison of Vin with a known-good machine to re-re-re-diagnose.

Comment: Jon - thanks for your help. I think I answered your questions. Let me know if you need further clarification.